# html multipart/form-data error in req.body using node/express

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express

I am using node, express, html and i am trying to post a  to my server side using  a html form. 
The problem is I get {} as my req.body.

My html form is the following:

```
    <form method = 'post' action='get_name' enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="form_name"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload name">
    </form>
```

I use the following in the begining of the my node.js file:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:'5mb', extended:false}));
app.use(busboy());
```

My app.post is the following:

```
app.post('/get_name',function(req, res, next){
        console.log("the name of the form is : ", req.body);
        res.redirect('/admin');
});
```

When i am trying to get req.body.form_name I get undefined. I cant find out what is wrong with my code. Any suggestions are welcome. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to use busboy, you should follow the documentation:

https://github.com/mscdex/busboy

Otherwise, bodyParser() does not support multi-part form data. I personally recommend this library for it's simplicity:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

This will populate req.body the way you are intending to use it.

Comment: since bodyParser() does not support multi-part form data, if you want to populate req.body, try using this library:https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer .. I personally use this over other options because of it's simplicity

Answer (score 0):

Use connect-multiparty module for multipart/form-data and add that in middleware of API route.

```
let multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
let multipartMiddleware = multipart();

 router.route('/customer').post(validate(validations.customerValidation.registerCustomer),multipartMiddleware,CONTROLLER.CustomerBaseController.registerCustomer);
```

It is working on my side.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
app.post('/get_name',function(req, res, next){
        console.log("to name of the form is : ", req.param('form_name'));
        res.redirect('/admin');
});
```

Comment: Might be worth `console.log()`ing your `req.params` above that other `console.log`, see if you can spot the correct info in there.